# javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path

Tags: java, resteasy

**Environment**

```
Windows 7(64)
jdk1.7.0_51(64)
RESTEasy3.0.7
apache-tomcat-7.0.50
Project Name: hello
```

**RESTEasyHelloWorldService.java:**

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.resteasy;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/RESTEasyHelloWorld")
public class RESTEasyHelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMsg(@PathParam("param") String name) {
        String msg = "Rest say: good " + name;
        return msg;
    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>hello</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
            </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

why do I get the exception when I call the `http://localhost:8080/hello/rest/RESTEasyHelloWorld/a` 
returns:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/hello/rest/RESTEasyHelloWorld/a
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:73)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
...
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try to use `http://localhost:8080/hello/RESTEasyHelloWorld/a`. (Without the `/rest`).

If you want to use `/rest`, you can modify your **RESTEasyHelloWorldService** @Path to `/rest/RESTEasyHelloWorld`.

---

But based on the APIs versions you are using, you can do a much simpler job to get your restful service working.

I'm assuming you have **resteasy-jaxrs** lib on your classpath.

Since you are not using JBOSS or EAP, you also need to get **resteasy-servlet-initializer**. Documentation for using **Servlet 3.0 Containers** like TOMCAT [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e111).

You will need to extend **Application**, creating for example a **RESTEasyService**:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RESTEasyService extends Application {
}
```

You don't need to provide any implementation for that class, since RESTEasy will scan for all providers and resources. Documentation for using **Application** class [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#javax.ws.rs.core.Application).

Leave your **RESTEasyHelloWorldService** just like you said on your question:

```
@Path("/RESTEasyHelloWorld")
public class RESTEasyHelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMsg(@PathParam("param") String name) {
        String msg = "Rest say: good " + name;
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Now your web.xml doesn't need anything. Java WS-RS and RESTEasy are already doing everything.

Your web.xml can be like this:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>hello</display-name>

</web-app>
```

RESTEasy official documentation is a little confusing at start, but once you understand that the implementation is the same for JBOSS and NON-JBOSS apps (just the use of libs that change), you get things going easier.

Comment: Could you please guide on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317022/could-not-find-messagebodywriter-for-response-object-of-type-java-util-arraylis?

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue when I tried with 3.0.11.Final

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>3.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

but when I tried with another version it worked.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>3.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And moreover The URL(http://localhost:8080/hello/rest/RESTEasyHelloWorld/a) which you are trying is correct since you have mentioned /rest in the web.xml .Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial to use RESTEasy 3](http://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was migrating my app from resteasy version 3.0.4 to 3.0.12

Web service was working fine with web.xml similar to one that user3926093 pasted above. What I released is that version 3.0.7 is changing point. Before that version you didn't even need resteasy-servlet-initializer as fasfsfgs stated above.  But with 3.0.7 and later versions I started getting "Could not find resource for full path:" exception.

What I did in order to make it work is to change web.xml to look the same as fasfsfgs stated above (basically I removed all configuration from it) and I created subclass of javax.ws.rs.core.Application class also as fasfsfgs stated above but I don't agree that "You don't need to provide any implementation for that class". The way how you could implement this class could be found here: https://goo.gl/9TJ3Y2. Note that if you want per-request model than this implementation is not good for you. And lastly don't forget to add resteasy-servlet-initializer dependency.

Answer (score 0):

```
I got the same issue when I tried with **3.13.2.Final** but when I tried with **3.6.3.Final** it worked.

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think you've found what @Raphael answered back in 2015 ... Is there anything else you can add that's new?