# Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: text/html - in Resteasy

Tags: java, jaxb, resteasy

I am developing **RESTEasy** Example. In this example I am using all latest dependencies and deploying om tomcat 8.x version. I can successfully deploy the application but when I am launching the url: http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/restwebservice/list, I see following errors are coming. Please guide what is going wrong here.

```
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: text/html
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:66)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:415)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code I developed so far for reference:
pom.xml

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <resteasy-jaxrs-version>3.0.16.Final</resteasy-jaxrs-version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy-jaxrs-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy-jaxrs-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Project Build -->
    <build>
        <finalName>RESTfulExample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Student.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Student {

    private int student_id;
    private String student_name;
    private String student_rollnumber;
    // setters and getters
}
```

RESTEasyService.java

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RESTEasyService extends Application{

}
```

RESTWebServiceJavaExample.java

```
@Path("/restwebservice")
public class RESTWebServiceJavaExample {
    private TreeMap<Integer, Student> webserviceMap= new TreeMap<>();

    public RESTWebServiceJavaExample(){

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setStudent_name("Ricky");
        student.setStudent_rollnumber("AOHP451");

        addStudent(student);

        student = new Student();
        student.setStudent_name("Mayer");
        student.setStudent_rollnumber("DKLP987");
        addStudent(student);

    }

    @GET
    @Path("list")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.addAll(webserviceMap.values());
        return students;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("add")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void addStudent(Student student_param) {
        int id = webserviceMap.size();
        student_param.setStudent_id(id);
        webserviceMap.put(id, student_param);
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now I am able to solve this issue. I need to add following dependency in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And 1) I should be using `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` on method signature to get following response.

```xml
<collection>
    <student>
        <student_id>0</student_id>
        <student_name>Ricky</student_name>
        <student_rollnumber>AOHP451</student_rollnumber>
    </student>
    <student>
        <student_id>1</student_id>
        <student_name>Mayer</student_name>
        <student_rollnumber>DKLP987</student_rollnumber>
    </student>
</collection>
```

2. If you want to use `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` then code will gives you following output which doesn't looks useful.

   [com.mkyong.rest.Student@4d5fd75e, com.mkyong.rest.Student@7715574d]

So use 1) solution.

Answer (score 30):

(For those who find the question, working with quarkus)

Using this setup routine:

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.16.1:create     -DprojectGroupId=com.sample     -DprojectArtifactId=hello-quarkus     -DclassName="com.sample.DemoEndpoint"     -Dpath="/persons"
```

To fix the issue described here, I had to add this dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

here is my full pom.xml after I added the above dependency.  Again, 99% of the below pom.xml came from the mvn command above.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-quarkus</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.version>0.16.1</quarkus.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- ADDED MAGIC HERE -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>native-image</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemProperties>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to add particular version of serializer

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Still a solution for 2023 (except now using **resteasy-jackson2-provider**)

Answer (score 7):

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

adding those annotations solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions provided by others works completely fine.

I just want to add, why they work?

RESTEasy is a JBoss / Red Hat project that provides various frameworks to help you build RESTful Web Services and RESTful Java applications. It does not have bindings to convert java classes from JSON and vice-versa.

Here comes libraries like JSON-B and Jackson, which helps to convert between java classes and JSON.

From Json-B documentation :

JSON-B is a standard binding layer for converting Java objects to/from JSON messages. It defines a default mapping algorithm for converting existing Java classes to JSON, while enabling developers to customize the mapping process through the use of Java annotations.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was about trying to serialize the array to XML. If you would like that it would need a wrapper class like this for movies:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "movies")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Movies
{
    @XmlElement(name = "movie")
    private List<Movie> movies;

    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }

    public void setMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }
}
```

This way it can be serialized under the root object.

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear, for beginners. add the

`@XmlRootElement(name = "yourClassLowerCased")` at the beginning of your class, like

```
package org.dlss.entities;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@Entity //The class will be a javax.persistence Entity (could be stored in a DB)
@Table(name = "person", schema = "public", catalog = "<databaseName>") //Table name
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class PersonEntity {


    @Id //Following field will be the id of the table
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) //Will be autoincremented when generated for type SERIAL into postgresql
    private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers, apart from the accepted solution make sure to use javax jaxb and not the jakarta one, works with one and not the other

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using quarkus version 3.1.1.Final, I have resolved replacing

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
  <version>${version.quarkus}</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>${version.quarkus}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate  Student.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```